# База данных. Вложенные таблицы

Tags: база-данных

Пишу своего чат-менеджера, возникла необходимость сделать таблицу с подтаблицей. Вот сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chats (
                chatId INT,
                title TEXT,
                stats TEXT)
```

В поле stats должен быть айди пользователей чата и их статистика, например:

```
{"123":{"messages":1, "photos":2, "videos":3}, "321":{"messages":5, "photos":6, "videos":7}}
```

Пока у меня это реализовано через JSON-строку, то есть я просто получаю её из поля, декодирую, и работаю как с обычным словарём. Насколько это правильно? Или это плохая практика и надо делать это средствами БД (БД sqlite3, но можете предложить свою)?

Comment: Идеальный вариант - одно поле, одно значение. Под разные сущности своя таблица и линковка по ID

Comment: *Насколько это правильно?* Неправильно. Заведи под статистику отдельную таблицу.